# T4Scaffolding - get list of files from a directory

Tags: powershell, t4scaffolding

usually what we do is for scaffolding we specify a model, the thing is i have more than hundred models, i want to get list of all the files from a namespace.project directory and run scaffolding against all of them.

I am using template in ps1 script to generate code

Comment: Hey. Use the DTE to get a specific project and directory. Then just iterate over the classes in that directory that meet your criteria. For each class found that you want to generate code on, call the scaffolder and pass in the information. I can provide some simple examples if needed ?

Comment: @Uffe. please do... the official documentations are scary for me

Comment: and please post as an answer so that i can accept

Answer (score 0):

This is a small PS script from my CodePlanner project. It might help you on the way..
http://pastebin.com/x5P7U42a

Comment: It's working for me, but throw me an email at uffe@xsockets.net and I will provide a sample